# The code below, is it ill-formed NDR or is it well formed?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, constexpr

Clang accepts the following code, but gcc [rejects it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e9d2a11d9a22b42).

```
void h() { }

constexpr int f() {
    return 1;
    h();
}

int main() {
    constexpr int i = f();
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
main.cpp: In function 'constexpr int f()':
main.cpp:5:6: error: call to non-'constexpr' function 'void h()'
     h();
     ~^~
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:9:24: error: 'constexpr int f()' called in a constant expression
     constexpr int i = f();
                       ~^~
main.cpp:9:19: warning: unused variable 'i' [-Wunused-variable]
     constexpr int i = f();
```

This could well be the case where both compilers are correct, once we consider [[dcl.constexpr]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#5), given that `f()` is not a constant expression, as it doesn't satisfy [[expr.const]/(4.2)](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#4.2), as it calls a non-constexpr function `h`. That is, the code is ill-formed, but no diagnostic is required.

One other possibility is that the code is well formed, as [expr.const]/(4.2) doesn't apply in this case because the call to `h` in `f` is not evaluated. If this is the case, `gcc` is wrong and `clang` is correct.

Comment: Clang does not allow calling `h()` before returning, so the real question here is: *Is a compiler allowed to ignore dead ill-formed code?*

Comment: "as it calls a non-constexpr function `h`". But it doesn't actually call `h`. I'd say that gcc is wrong here.

Comment: I'm adding the C++14 tag since on C++11 there's no question that it's ill-formed.

Comment: This code works in GCC's trunk.. https://godbolt.org/z/f04MCq  and https://godbolt.org/z/bAyE8a .. So it's already fixed.. Free upvotes. If compiled with GCC 8.3 it will fail but compile with Trunk and it works fine.

Answer (score 24):

Clang is correct. A call to `f()` is a constant expression since the call to `h()` is never evaluated, so [dcl.constexpr]/5 doesn't apply. The call to `h()` in the body of `f()` is not ill-formed because the [constraints](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#3) on `constexpr` functions don't say anything about not being allowed to call non-`constexpr` functions. Indeed, a function like the following is well-formed because a call to it can be a constant expression when `x` is odd:

```
constexpr int g(int x) {
    if (x%2 == 0) h();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You answer seems to be correct, but I don't agree with your reasoning. Consider this: `constexpr int f() { h(); return 1; }`. In this case the code is ill-formed NDR according to [\[dcl.constexpr\]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#5) because the function `f` invokes a non-constexpr function `h`, and this is not allowed according to [\[expr.const\]/(4.2)](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#4.2). See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34272899/2337207) in SO.

Comment: @Alexander In the case where the call to `h()` is before the return statement, every call to `f` will fail to be a constant expression, and [dcl.constexpr]/5 applies. In the case where the call to `h()` is after the return statement, every call to `f` will be a constant expression, so [dcl.constexpr]/5 does not apply.

Comment: Ok, but why did you say "The call to h() in the body of f() is not ill-formed because the constraints on constexpr functions don't say anything about not being allowed to call non-constexpr functions."? This is what is confusing in your answer.

Comment: @Alexander I'm not sure what part of that was unclear. I linked a section of the standard that lists the constructs that are forbidden from appearing in a `constexpr` function's body. A call to a non-`constexpr` function is not one of the forbidden constructs. However, if the call to the non-`constexpr` function becomes inevitable (i.e., occurs along all paths) then [dcl.constexpr]/5 becomes violated.

Comment: Well, I suppose you could resume your answer to just this: "Clang is correct. A call to `f()` is a constant expression since the call to `h()` is never evaluated, so [dcl.constexpr]/5 doesn't apply." But I'm still missing a quote from the standard confirming that the call to `h()` is never evaluated. For example, [dcl.constexpr]/5 doesn't say anything about this.

Comment: @Alexander According to the rules of the language, the `return` statement returns control to the caller, skipping all remaining statements in the function. What about this is unclear?