# Why is string's operator+ that takes an r-value reference declared to return by value?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to come to terms with r-value references. I discovered that string's operator+ is always declared to return by value.

Why is operator+ defined to return by value:

```
basic_string operator+(basic_string&& lhs, const basic_string& rhs) {
   return move( lhs.append(rhs) );
}
```

Why is it not defined like the following:

```
basic_string&& operator+(basic_string&& lhs, const basic_string& rhs) {
   return move( lhs.append(rhs) );
}
```

Is this somehow invalid code?

Comment: Because that would be much riskier? `const std::string & r = std::string("a") + std::string("b");`

Comment: From [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963974/are-returned-locals-automatically-xvalues) I understand that the compilers are free to consider the return value as an rvalue anyway.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: Nobody disputes that the return value should be an rvalue. The question is why it is a prvalue and not an xvalue.