# Does an implementation that returns fundamental types by value using registers do "temporary materialization"?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, copy-elision, return-by-value

***(c++20; Working Draft N4868)***

**[stmt.return]/2** says that the return statement initializes the glvalue result or prvalue result object by copy initialization

> the return statement initializes the glvalue result or prvalue result object of the (explicit or
> implicit) function call by copy-initialization (9.4) from the operand.

For class types, the return statement "invokes" the selected constructor and copy-initialize the variable obj, the result object of the invocation, because the copy-elision (an implementation is the caller to pass the address of the dest, so that the called function initialize the dest by constructor call)

```
class MyClass {
  int x;
};

MyClass func() {
  return MyClass(); //initializes the result object of the function call
}

int main() {
  MyClass obj {func()}; //obj is the result object of func().
}
```

**[dcl.init.general]/16.6.1** suggests:

> If the initializer expression is a prvalue and the cv-unqualified
> version of the source type is the same class as the class of the
> destination, the initializer expression is used to initialize the
> destination object

For fundamental types like int, double, etc., the common implementation is the return statement to copy the operand (return expression) to the registers

(gcc 12.1 -std=c++20)

```
int func() {
  return 2;
}

int main() {
  int myInt {func()}; 
}
```

---

```
func():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     eax, 2
        pop     rbp
        ret
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        call    func()
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], eax
        mov     eax, 0
        leave
        ret
```

In **[class.temporary]/1.2**, the standard says that is it possible to materialize temporaries if the type is "trivially copyable":

> 1 Temporary objects are created
>
> [...]
>
> —(1.2) when needed by the implementation to pass or return an object
> of trivially copyable type (see below),
>
> [...]

**Question**:

- Does implementation like that for fundamental types (int, double, etc.) uses the [class.temporary]/1.2 as source?
- If yes, then does the function call materialize an temporary (using registers) and the return statement initialize that temporary by copy-initialization?

---

Related

[Initialization in return statements of functions that return by-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68883573/initialization-in-return-statements-of-functions-that-return-by-value)

Comment: I do want to point out one thing, a cart and horses matter: it's not that implementations use [class.temporary]/1.2 as a source and decide to do it. It's [class.temporary]/1.2 that exists because implementations *wanted* to pass certain types in register. The reason is efficiency, and the standard makes it permissible in types that seeminigly fit a certain mold for passing in registers.

Comment: _[dcl.init.general]/16.6.1 suggests_ For `MyClass obj {func()};`?! You are wrong. [dcl.init.general]/16.6.1 does not apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does an implementation that returns fundamental types by value using registers do "temporary materialization"?

Yes.

> Does implementation like that for fundamental types (int, double, etc.) uses the [class.temporary]/1.2 as source?

[class.temporary]/(1.2) is a non-normative reference to [[class.temporary]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.temporary#3), and an implementation can not use it for non-class types, which is the subject of [CWG2434](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2434.html):

> ##### 2434. Mandatory copy elision vs non-class objects
>
> In the following example,
>
> ```cpp
>  int f() {
>    X x;
>    return 4;
>  }
>  int a = f();
> ```
>
> `a` must be directly initialized in the return statement of `f()` because the exception permitting temporaries for function arguments and return types in [class.temporary] paragraph 3 applies only to certain class types.
>
> This requirement is observable, since the destructor of `X` in the example could inspect the value of `a`.
>
> The permissions in this paragraph should also apply to all non-class types.

Answer (score 4):

The standard describes **behavior**, not implementation.  Put differently, a CPU register is not an object; the presence of whatever value in whatever register is not a copy in any sense recognized by the language or (equivalently) observable by the program (since fundamental types do not have special member functions that might detect them!).

Similarly, the view of a running program with a debugger need not correspond to any state visited by the program.  The implementation uses things like registers to provide the language’s semantics, but it does not need **permission** from the standard to do so in any particular fashion.